# how to change k4dirstat folder browsing action?

Tags: mime-types

Changing the cleanup action "Open a file browser" directly on the settings won't be saved.
So, `~/.config/k4dirstatrc` will not store anything about cleanup actions (not implemented?).
So, on next run of k4dirstat, that change would be lost.
That action uses `xdg-open %p`
I prefer nemo filemanager.

Answer (score 0):

configuring `mimeopen -d SomeFolder` wont affect xdg-open...

so:

```
$xdg-mime query filetype SomeFolder
inode/directory
$xdg-mime query default "inode/directory"
nautilus-folder-handler.desktop
$locate nautilus-folder-handler.desktop
/usr/share/applications/nautilus-folder-handler.desktop
$ls /usr/share/applications/*.desktop
...
$xdg-mime default nemo.desktop "inode/directory"
```

of course, this will affect not only k4dirstat but any other app that uses `xdg-open %p` (what is good to me).

but... changing it only for k4dirstat would be a better answer, anyone knows?